# Function same height for different rows

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my code :

```html
<section class="highlight">
  <div class="member">
    content 1 (height 200px)
  </div>
  <div class="member">
    content 2 (height 300px)
  </div>
  <div class="member">
    content 3 (height 150px)
  </div>
</section>

<section class="highlight">
  <div class="member">
    content 1 (height 400px)
  </div>
  <div class="member">
    content 2 (height 600px)
  </div>
  <div class="member">
    content 3 (height 250px)
  </div>
</section>
```

And the jQuery code I found :

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.equalHeights = function(){
      var max_height = 0;
      $(this).each(function(){
        max_height = Math.max($(this).height(), max_height);
      });
      $(this).each(function(){
        $(this).height(max_height);
      });
    };
    $('.member').equalHeights();
  });
```

In this case, the jQuery code will apply a height of 600px to all div with .member class. But I would like the code to apply 300px for the first section, and 600px for the second. How can I do ?

Edit : just add an image for everyone better understand :
[image: explanation of the problem]

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, but this is just an example to show my mind, I am using h-100 class on other parts of my website and it works well, but in this special case I need to use jQuery...

Comment: it's not clear to me what you want to do. can you show a diagram of what you're looking for

Comment: Sure, here is an image : https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2019/12/06//19120610271915813.png I hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to find a way to select "member" elements from one section at a time.
If that is the case, Try

```
 $(".member",$("section")[0])  //selects "member" elements from first section.
 $(".member",$("section")[1])  //selects "member" elements from second section.
```

Then do the required changes.

Eg:

```
$(".member",$("section")[0]).equalHeights(); // First section.
$(".member",$("section")[1]).equalHeights(); // Second section.
```

If you have a scenario where there would be more "section" elements, determine it's index under "equalHeights" method, by referring to current "memebers" parent index and calculate height accordingly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.fn.equalHeights = function(){   
  var max_height = 0;
  $(this).each(function(){

    var currentSectionIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log("currnetSectionIndex " + currentSectionIndex);

    // Make calculation as per the section index
    max_height = Math.max($(this).height(), max_height);

  });
  $(this).each(function(){
    $(this).height(max_height);
  });
};
 $('.member').equalHeights();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks but what if there is more than two highlight sections ? I am using flexible content so I don't know how many section of same type will be used by users...

Comment: @Yann: I updated the answer.  You can determine the "index" of the section in your equalHeights method, under "$(this).each". check the "memeber"s parent "section" index and calculate the height according to that.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use jQuery nowadays to do this but CSS flex or grid.